# OpenGL ES iPhone drawing only works when profiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I have a very simple triangle class that uses NSMutableData to store vertex information. The triangle class models somewhat after the class found in [this tutorial](http://games.ianterrell.com/how-to-draw-2d-shapes-with-glkit/). The triangle only draws itself when profiling the app, but not when running it normally. I don't have much experience with NSMutableData, so I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem. My app also uses GLKit. What is different when profiling an app that would cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently, GLKTextureInfo objects don't work when profiling. I forgot to disable the texture2d0 property of my GLKBaseEffect, so it was trying to draw the texture onto it. It worked when profiling because the textures didn't work.